# How to quote from a source in a different language

Tags: citations, plagiarism

I'm writing an essay in English, but much of my source material is in Spanish (my first language). I know how to reference my sources in the bibliography, but how do I quote within the text? Do I translate it myself and still use quotation marks?

Comment: Exact citation standards differ from field to field. As a general principle, you should make it clear that it's a translation and who translated it.

Answer (score 2):

Your method sounds good. Indicate somehow that you translated, either by saying so once at the beginning of your essay, or individually with each quotation.

*General advice:* Who are you writing this for?  If for a a class, ask the instructor.  If for a journal, consult the editor.

Answer (score 2):

In APA 6th and 7th editions, translations done by the author (you) are considered paraphrases. To cite these in-text, you add (Author, Year). at the end of a sentence as you normally would.  These in-text citations do not require quotations.